# What is the meaning of the three dots in the object?

Tags: javascript, angularfire2

Piece of code from angularfire in firestore query.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

return { id, **...data** };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why that's referred to as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)! :)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the name of that operator.